# gensim.corpora Dictionary type error interprets tokenized column as single string

Tags: python, dictionary, gensim

here is the problematic code:

```
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
tweets_dictionary = Dictionary(df.tokenized)
```

the Panda Dataframe df is build as followed with two columns "created_at" and "tokenized". "tokenized" consists of a list of words:

[image: df.head()]

I get the following error message while running the problematic code:

`TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string`

This is very bizzare to me, as the column tokenized is not a single string. I have tried converting the column into a single list, a list of lists and a tuple, but nothing has worked so far....thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I am dumb: putting the "df.tokenized" into a list worked, I just forgot to save the code before execution.

So the correct code would be:

```
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
tweets_dictionary = Dictionary([df.tokenized])
```

Comment: Double-check the keys in that `tweets_dictionary` to see if they're what you expect. It's possible you've just managed to use a list-with-a-single-string as each `tokenized` value, where that single string looks like a Python list's string representation, instead of what `Dictionary` really wants, which is a true Python `list` object with multiple entries, each of which is a word-token. (That is, you might now just be supplying a bunch of 1-item-lists like `["['foo', 'bar', 'baz']"]` where instead it wants multi-item lists like `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`)